# Xamarin Cross Firebase Push Notification crash

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification, cross-platform

I am using the latest version of FirebasePushNotificationPlugin, 3.3.10

Everything is fine, it works great,

but when receiving a notification while the application is on screen, the app crash with error:

Unhandled Exception:

System.MissingMethodException: string[] string.Split(char,System.StringSplitOptions)

Note: I am not using any "Split" anywhere, I am sure this error is not from any of my own code.

it works fine if the app is close, or even opened but not active on screen.

I tried to remove the "NotificationRecieved" event, but the same error appears.
No change if I sued "CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += NotificationRecieved;" or not.

Help, please

Comment: Hi , do you have a check with the structure of received message whether is correct , and whether to send the message in the format required by the document ?

Comment: Does this error occur on all platforms? Another problem like this occurred a few times ago and was resolved with the Visual Studio update.

Comment: Thanks, Junior Jiang: Yes I am sure of the message format. I follow the documents step by step.

Comment: Thanks, Filipe Piletti: This happen with all platforms, only if the app active in the front of the screen.

Comment: I downgrade the "Plugin.FirebasePushNotification" from 3.3.10 to the 2.3.5, which was the last working version for me, and the error disappear. I am sad to be forced to use such old version, but this is the only solution for me right now. Regards